# Is there a limit definition to partial derivatives with dependent variables?

Tags: limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm wondering about the form that a limits definition of partial derivatives should take when we partially derivate a function of dependent and independent variables wrt to an independent variable.

More precisely stated, the question is: Given two functions $\{f,g\}\in \mathcal{C}^1$ (such that their first derivatives exist, and such that $f$ has partial derivatives everywhere) let:
$$f'=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,g(x))$$
Expanding the RHS we get:
$$f'=\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
Both $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ have a precise definition using limits, so the first term its not problematic... But i do not know how to define the second term in terms of limits. Should i use:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{∆\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+∆,g(x+∆))-f(x,g(x))}{∆}$$
or rather:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{∆\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+∆,g(x))-f(x,g(x))}{∆}$$
Wich of the previous identities gives the right equation to $f'$?

Comment: your notations are not good. let $f=f(x,y)$. If $p(x)=f(x,g(x))$, then $$p'(x)=\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x} f(x,g(x))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+g'(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}.$$ But you can't write $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,g(x))$ for $\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}f(x,g(x))$. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is really a notation to specify the derivative of $f$ w.r.t. the first variable.

Comment: So, we can say that the partial derivative symbol only acts on the variable's position in the function's arguments, not on the whole variable. In this case, the second equation is correct (although my notation, then, makes no sense.)

Comment: yes it's correct... it's known as chain rule, even though, writting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$ is not really optimal...